# Assembly MASM : program that sorts dword unsigned integer array in descending order

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I'm confused with my assignment. The question is :
Write a complete program that sorts dword unsigned integer array in descending order.

Assume that the user doesn’t enter more than 40 integers.

You MUST use the template and follow all the directions there.

You can’t add any more procedures to the template.
The procedures can’t use any global variables (variables that are inside .data segment).
The caller of any procedures sends its argument through the stack.
Inside any procedures, if you need to use a register, you have to preserve its original value. You can't use uses, pushad operators.
The callee is in charge of cleaning the stack.
Your lines must not exceed 80 columns
Add a sample run at the end of your program. Submit the .asm file by Thursday 9th, 8 AM.

Sample run:

> Enter up to 40 unsigned dword integers. To end the array, enter 0.
>   After each element press enter:
>    1
>   4
>   3
>   8
>   99
>   76
>   34
>   5
>   2
>   17
>   0
>   
>   Initial array:
>   
>   1 4 3 8 99 76 34 5 2 17
>   
>   Array sorted in descending order:
>   
>   99 76 34 17 8 5 4 3 2 1
>   
>   Press any key to continue . . .

For now, what I have is:

```
include irvine32.inc
      ; ===============================================
      .data

     array dword 40 dup(?)
     string1 byte "Enter up to 40 unsigned dword integers. To end the array,     enter 0.",0
     string2 byte "After each element press enter:", 0
     string3 byte "Initial array:",0
     string4 byte "Array sorted in descending order:",0

     ;=================================================
        .code
         main proc
    ; YOU NEED TO CALL ENTER_ELEM, SORT_ARR AND PRINT_ARR PROCEDURES

    mov edx, offset string1
    call writeString
    call crlf
    call crlf

    mov edx, offset string2
    call writeString
    call crlf

    mov esi, offset array
    mov ecx, LENGTHOF array
    push esi
    mov eax, 0
       L1:
      call    Readdec         ; read integer into EAX
          mov [esi],eax           ; store in array
      cmp eax, 0
      JE end01
          add esi,TYPE array      ; next integer
      call enter_elem
      loop L1

         end01: 
          mov edx, offset string3
      call writeString

      call print_arr

         exit
         main endp

       ; ================================================
       ; void enter_elem(arr_addr)
       ;
       ; Input:
       ;   ARR_ADDRESS THROUGH THE STACK
       ; Output:
       ;   ARR_LENGTH THROUGH THE STACK
       ; Operation:
       ;   ?
       ;
        enter_elem proc
    push ebp          ;set ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    push eax          ; save register
    mov esi, [ebp + 12]; pointing to value in array
    mov ecx, [ebp+8]
    add esi, 4        ; move pointer to next value in array
    pop eax
    pop ebp

        ret 4
        enter_elem endp
        ; ================================================
        ; void print_arr(arr_addr,arr_len)
        ;
        ; Input:
        ;   ?
        ; Output:
        ;   ?
        ; Operation:
        ;   ?
        ;

        print_arr proc

        push ebp          ;set ebp
        mov ebp, esp
        push eax

        L2:
        mov eax, DWORD ptr [esi] ;store in new array        
        call writeDec
    add esi, TYPE array      ;next integer
    mov al,', '
    call writeChar           ;Displays value in EAX
        loop L2
         pop eax 
         pop ebp

         ret 4
         print_arr endp
```

Thank you, I would really appreciate the help : I don't know where I got wrong, why I can't print out the initial array.

Comment: I guess (from the comment describing in/out) the `enter_elem` was meant to handle whole array input. You give it target address of buffer (but not max length, so malicious user can overflow it, but that's what the task says.. *"Assume"* ... eh), and it returns filled buffer with values and its size on stack. I don't think it's worth to comment on your code, that main part makes some sense, but that `enter_elem` is like random garbage copied it, with wrong comments (how does `push ebp` "set ebp"? A to what? And why? Why ebp+12? If you would debug it in debugger, some of those would be obvious.

Comment: Oh, I got it, so the loop to get the input should be in the enter_elem procedure right? I don't really understand stack. But I've tried this, and now it will only take 1 input.

Comment: Here is general explanation of stack http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/assembly/4957/the-stack#t=201703081038431522121 (examples are for Z80 CPU, that's close to x86, if you focus on principles it should help) I was unable to find some **thorough** tutorial for stdcall (looks closest to your calling convention, except return values are in `eax`, not through stack, you may check also cdecl calling convention, where caller cleans stack, but arguments are passed the same way). Rather check examples/notes of your course (that return through stack needs definition any way, it's not common).

Comment: But anyway, you *MUST* understand the stack to have any chance to proceed further. If you put that loop into `enter_elem`, you have to first set up the frame pointer `ebp` correctly, and load the first (and only) argument, which will be the array address. `mov esi, offset array` should be not part of it, that should convert to `push offset array` ahead of call. And then if you don't cleanup stack correctly at end of subroutine, you will return to wrong code (wrong number from stack used as return address), and you should release correct amount of N bytes by `ret N` to restore stack.

Comment: Hmm.. that stack doc... maybe that ascii art will help mostly... if you can re-imagine it with 32bit values instead of 16... And you must have debugger to verify your own code, if you have one, there's certainly a way to view stack memory, so you can watch it ahead/after `call enter_elem` to see how the `ebp` pointer related to that content, and where your array offset is stored. *"by Thursday 9th"* that's sort of ridiculous with your current level of asm knowledge. If it is like you have quite some knowledge but you are confused, maybe it will "click", but it looks like you need another 2-4w.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I got it, so the loop to get the input should be in the enter_elem procedure right? I don't really understand stack. But I've tried this, and now it will only take 1 input.

```
                                                                                     enter_elem proc
mov eax, 0
    L1:
call    Readdec         ; read integer into EAX
    mov [esi],eax           ; store in array
cmp eax, 0
JE end01
    push ebp          
mov ebp, esp
push eax          ; save register
push esi          ; save register
mov esi, [ebp+12]  ; pointing to value in array
add esi,4
```

pop esi
    pop eax
    pop ebp
    add esi, 4        ; move pointer to next value in array

```
    end01: 

   ret 4
   enter_elem endp
```